# Retrieving text from comments section?

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve text from a comments section but I'm unsure as to why this code only works once. Has anyone had a similar problem?

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

results = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/RobinHoodPennyStocks/comments/hegob7/no_body_liked_my_post_last_time_but_its_mooning/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

comments = [] 

comments_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='_3cjCphgls6DH-irkVaA0GM')

for container in comments_div:

  name = container.p.text

  comments.append(name)

print(comments)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only works once"? Any particular error?

Comment: That class looks suspiciously like a dynamically generated value. Have you checked it remains stable over time?